# Apache user_dir module failed

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, centos6.2, mod-userdir

I'm trying to setup user_dir module in my DEVSERVER but gets a 404 Not found error any time I try to reach any URL like for example:

```
http://devserver/~reynierpm/
```

My userdir.conf file is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir enabled guillermo reynierpm tomas

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
      Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Allow from all
      Order deny,allow
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I'm running CentOS 6.3 with latest Apache 2.2.15!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is missing the LoadModule and the UserDir configuration is not complete. Your configuration should be:

```
LoadModule userdir_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so

<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled
    UserDir enabled guillermo reynierpm tomas

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
            Order deny,allow
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**: If you need only those users you must have `UserDir disabled`, not `UserDir disabled root`